# Downcasting from an Arc<Mutex<dyn Trait>> in Rust?

Tags: rust, downcast

I have a structure like this:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Wrapper {
    object: Arc<Mutex<dyn MyTrait>>,
}

struct MyStruct1;

impl MyStruct1 {
    fn specific_method(&self) {
        println!("specific method");
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct1 {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("struct 1 is doing something");
    }
}

fn add_object_1(vector: &mut Vec<Wrapper>) {
    let object_1: MyStruct1 = MyStruct1 {};
    vector.push(Wrapper {
        object: Arc::new(Mutex::new(object_1)),
    });
}

fn do_something_with_struct_1(object: MyStruct1) {
    object.specific_method();
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_objects: Vec<Wrapper> = Vec::new();

    // add from a different scope
    add_object_1(&mut my_objects);

    // get back object_1 from my_objects
    let wrapper: Wrapper = my_objects[0].clone();
    let object_1_guard: MutexGuard<'_, dyn MyTrait> = wrapper.object.lock().unwrap();

    // somehow get back to a MyStruct1
    let object_1: MyStruct1 = todo!(); // ???
    do_something_with_struct_1(object_1);
}
```

Essentially, there's some data structure storing a bunch of wrappers that themselves store a dynamic reference to a MyTrait object. I am currently wrapping it in `Arc<Mutex<>>` because that is the only way I found to enable cloning my Wrapper (which I need)

My question is now, how do I get back the specific object I added from a different function / scope from my vector?

I tried solutions from a different question that involved casting it as `Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync>` (and added the `Send + Sync` requirements to MyTrait) but that did not work, because "the size for values of type `(dyn MyTrait + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time" and the cast requires it.

I can't change it to an Enum either, because I want to be able to add new MyTrait objects from outside the crate which, to my knowledge is impossible with Enums

Comment: Its generally an anti-pattern to downcast from a dynamic trait object. You should instead strive to mold the type to fit the trait - or vice versa: mold the trait with capabilities that you want implementations to achieve. Though that's just general advice and people do it anyway (and the std library supports it, though in a limited way). Are you sure this is the direction you want to take to solve your current conundrum? Another route is to use an `enum` if your implementers are a closed set and have special behavior for each.

Comment: I just made an answer addressing your question here: [How to do runtime polymorphism using Arc<Mutex<dyn SomeTrait>> in Rust?](/q/68173030/2189130) Or perhaps [Rust: Upcasting an Arc<dyn Trait> to an Arc<dyn Any>?](/q/76222743/2189130) or [Is it possible to downcast Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync> to Arc<Mutex<String>>?](/q/64409837/2189130) may be of help?

Comment: @kmdreko i don‘t quite understand what you mean by “mold your type to fit the trait”. the requirements i have made it difficult for me to get anything working at all. i need to be able to put any rust struct in it so long as it has certain functions, i needed to be able to clone it, and i needed the trait to be object safe somewhere in there. arc mutex dyn trait was the only thing that worked, but if you have other suggestions, i’d love to hear them :)

Comment: okay, i tried some of your suggestions but it always ends up requiring "Sized" somehow and, well, I have a dyn Trait so that ain't happening

Comment: If those didn't help, you should show the actual code and operations you need (in the post itself, not a github link). Alternatively, show your attempts with the resources I linked; they should not require `Sized` in places where `dyn Trait` is needed.

Comment: [Applying the dupe](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dec59bc2f94c7fafce60a05b937da982) works. Of course you can't get a owned thing from a shared `Arc` without making sure it's unique (by removing it from the vec) or cloning the inner struct.